# Why is my .htaccess with mod_rewrite giving me a 500 error?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff|svg)">
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 </FilesMatch>

ErrorDocument 400 /errors/400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)\.(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.domain.com/page?user=%1 [L,QSA,R=302,NE]

***THIS IS WHERE I INSERT THE NEW RULE***

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-([0-9]+)\.html$ product?name=$1&product_id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

So far so good. It all works. When someone goes to `scoobydoo.domain.com` for example they are redirected to `domain.com/page?user=scoobydoo`. Now I also want to **mask** the page so that when someone goes to `www.domain.com/scoobydoo` they are really shown `domain.com/page?user=scoobydoo`, so I add this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /page?user=$1 [L]
```

When I add this to the 2nd last line however, it doesn't work.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Yep! It works indeed...

Answer (score 1):

Your rule is ok, but you need to exclude your real files and dirs from it :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /page?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Strangely that's giving me a 500 error :( Trying to move the rules up or down now to see if that works ...

Comment: @num8er - OP stated that the subdomain -> page rule works. So mod_rewrite is enabled...

Comment: Weird. It's got to be something wrong with the other rules messing it up. Can't figure out what though.